# React setState wipes getters and setters from the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to impletement a function that makes some properties in an object dependent on some other prop, or, `computed`. This idea is largely influenced by [`computed` in vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#computed). The function looks like this:

```
// given `destPairs` is like `{destProp: computer}`,
// this function sets `host[srcProp]` to `value`, and re-compute `host[destProp]` using `computer` when `host[srcProp]` changes
function defineComputed(host, srcProp, value, destPairs) {
  Object.defineProperty(host, srcProp, {
    set(newVal) {
      this.__my_store = this.__my_store || {};
      this.__my_store[srcProp] = newVal;
      for(const destProp in destPairs) {
        const computer = destPairs[destProp];
        this[destProp] = computer(newVal);
      }
    },
    get() {
      return this.__my_store[srcProp];
    }
  });
  host[srcProp] = value;
}
```

The function seems to work fine except when I use `setState`, all getters/settters defined in the state by this function are wiped out so I can't achieve my goal. Here is [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JJPandari/k8oxwqek/), check the console and you can see there're getters/settters, but if you uncomment the `setState`, the getters/settters are gone.

How `setState` exactly works may answer this question so I tried to read it, but stepping into `setState` I only see something like `this.updater.enqueueSetState` but not the code who really changes the state, so I was unable to find how react changes the state.

Answer (score 2):

**Regarding the Why**

From the official [react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> You may optionally pass an object as the first argument to setState() instead of a function:`setState(stateChange[, callback])` 
>   This performs a ***shallow merge*** of stateChange into the new state

Please note the emphasis on *shallow*. This nukes out any getters and setters you may have. See the MDN docs for [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) description.

**Suggestion for avoiding what you are seeing**

I do not know why you need getters and setters in your state. Official & accepted advice is to avoid mutating the state directly and use the `setState` method.

However, if you have to have them for some reason or the other, 
I would suggest looking at [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) and creating an object with the getters to set it to. My assumption here is that you need to setState based on some prop changing.

Comment: `getDerivedStateFromProps` is helpful but doesn't exactly do what I want since it syncs two values, one in parent, one in child, while I want them to be in one component; `Object.assign` **does** invoke getters and setters without nuking them, quoting MDN, `It uses [[Get]] on the source and [[Set]] on the target, so it will invoke getters and setters. Therefore it assigns properties versus just copying or defining new properties.` I tried it myself, the getter and setter do stay after `assign`.