# Accessing a state object in the this.state constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state with 2 objects (players), of which only 1 can be the player on turn.

How do I save the player on turn into the state, so I can use its data?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      playerOne: {
        name: "foo"
      },
      playerTwo: {
        name: "bar"
      }
      playerOnTurn: {} // This has to become the same Object as 'playerOne'.
    }
  }
}
```

---

I have tried the following 3 things:

---

**1)** Directly accessing the state (within the state):

```
playerOnTurn: this.state.playerOne
```

Unfortunately **it doesn't work**, as the state isn't yet defined due to still constructing the state.

---

**2)** Writing the same Object twice:

```
playerOnTurn: { name: "foo" }
```

**It works**, but I don't want to write it twice, because a player can contain many properties. It seems like a bad solution in terms maintainability. Because properties could be added/removed later, which could cause them to become nonidentical.

---

**3)** Declaring the object before setting it in the state:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const playerOne = {
      name: "foo"
    }

    this.state = {
      playerOne: playerOne,
      playerTwo: {
        name: "bar"
      }
      playerOnTurn: playerOne
    }
  }
}
```

**It works**, but it doesn't seem like a great solution in terms of readability. Because I declare both players in different ways.

---

Maybe it requires a different approach? E.g. by adding a boolean `onTurn` to each player?

Any input/advice is welcome.

Comment: your 3rd option is correct. you are not declaring both players in different ways. you are declaring one player and holding two references to that same object, one in playerOne and one in playerOnTurn

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a getter function, which allows you to access `this` (in context of the object) inside a function:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      playerOne: {
        name: "foo"
      },,
      playerTwo: {
        name: "bar"
      }
      get playerOnTurn() {
        return this.playerOne
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @UniqIdentifierAssignedAtBirth there is? `this` in this context is the object, not the class.

Comment: It does work, `this` refers to the Object: `this.state` in this case. Thank you for the answer, it was exactly what I needed. :)

Comment: Regardless, you cannot set the player on turn when you need to so it's not practical. More importantly, you can't put getters and setters inside react state objects. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387670/react-setstate-wipes-getters-and-setters-from-the-state They will get wiped when you setState

Comment: @UniqIdentifierAssignedAtBirth You can with a lazy getter, that of which will grab it when it is called

Comment: @Daan no problem, as for hooks, I would recommend looking into them, they are very useful, and definitely the next step from classes :)

Comment: You can't use setters and getters with react state. you have to use `setState` and pure objects

Comment: You can use getters, it is only when you call setState that they will be cleared since setState only keeps a shallow copy of state. @UniqIdentifierAssignedAtBirth

Comment: Exactly, so what is the point of putting a getter inside a state object?

Comment: @UniqIdentifierAssignedAtBirth to get the value initially? I don't know OP's needs, only that they needed to set it immediately during construction

Comment: Uniq is right, putting a getter inside a state object is bound to cause problems. It's also unnecessary since the 3rd option already does what OP wants without the downsides.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you should use componentDidMount lifecycle method to update your state.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      playerOne: {
        name: "foo"
      },,
      playerTwo: {
        name: "bar"
      }
      playerOnTurn: {}
    }
  }

  setPlayerOnTurn(player){
      this.setState({ playerOnTurn : player });
  }

  componentDidMount(){
      // other initialization
      this.setPlayerOnTurn(this.state.playerOne);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not the same as OP wants and the first render will lack the `playerOnTurn` value.

Comment: To have the value before mounting, you can either use [componentWillMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount) or [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops). These methods are called before render method and will ensure playerOnTurn is available on first render. @EmileBergeron

Comment: `componentWillMount` is deprecated and `getDerivedStateFromProps` is called each time the props changes, which will lead to an unnecessary complex implementation instead of just doing it in the state initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Your 3rd option is correct, if you want it to not look like you are declaring them in different ways, you can do,

```
    const playerOne = {
      name: "foo"
    }

    const playerTwo = {
      name: "bar"
    }

    this.state = {
      playerOne,
      playerTwo,
      playerOnTurn: playerOne
    }
```